# FirstLetterCaps as like item.toLowerCase()

Tags: javascript, string, knockout.js

I am having details like,

```
DataSet: Group: [Subvalues]
    Fruits: [Orange, Apple]
    Chocolate: [Dairy Milk, Kit Kat]
```

These are static items which are initially pushed during variable initialisation. Now I would like to categorise some items dynamically so that it would get pushed into each concerned group.

Say for example, If I give `FRUITS: Pine Apple` it should be added as the third item in `Fruits` group, but it is adding to a new group name `"FRUITS"` full caps,

I have tried like pushing all these elements all small then it worked fine like,

```
fruits: [orange, apple, pine apple]
```

But, Actually, I would like to make the first letter of each word caps like,

```
Fruits: [Orange, Apple, Pine Apple]
```

Final object mapping is like,

```
var value = ko.observableArray([]);
value(FRUITS: Pine Apple, Fruits: Apple, Fruits: Orange, Chocolate: Dairy Milk, Chocolate: Kit Kat);

var mapUpdated = value().reduce(function (map, item) {
                  var key = item.split(':')[0];
                  map[key] = map[key] || [];
                  map[key].push(item.split(':')[1] || []);
                  return map;
              }, {});
```

This updated map is showing details like,

```
FRUITS: Pine Apple
Fruits: Apple, Orange
Chocolate: Dairy Milk, Kit Kat
```

I have to push Pine Apple to Fruits group.

Any help/suggestion on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalize the first letter, and convert all the others to lower case:

```
var selectedSkillCluster = ko.observableArray([]);
selectedSkillCluster(FRUITS: Pine Apple, Fruits: Apple, Fruits: Orange, Chocolate: Dairy Milk, Chocolate: Kit Kat);

var mapUpdated = selectedSkillCluster().reduce(function (map, item) {
  var key = item.split(':')[0];
  key = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  map[key] = map[key] || [];
  map[key].push(item.split(':')[1] || []);
  return map;
}, {});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)